# CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale doesn't work with C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV and `CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale` for facial detection. My problem is that it seems to cause memory corruption on the output `vector<Rect>`. The vector is correctly filled with Rects, but it causes a crash when the vector is deallocated.

This only occurs when compiling a Debug build. The error message is a Debug Assertion Failed, which makes me wonder if there is a problem that also occurs in Release build, and the assert simply isn't checked.

Could this be a bug with OpenCV? Or is it just that I'm doing something wrong with how I handle my vectors?

The following code snippet shows an example code to reproduce the bug:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    VideoCapture video(0);
    Mat frame;
    CascadeClassifier classifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");

    while (waitKey(1000 / 30) != 'q')
    {
        video >> frame;

        vector<Rect> faces;
        classifier.detectMultiScale(frame, faces);
        for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
            rectangle(frame, faces[i], Scalar(255, 255, 255));

        imshow("Camera", frame);
    } // <<< The crash occurs here when the faces vector is released
}
```

I get the following error message:

Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: MyProgram.exe
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\heap\debug_heap.cpp
Line: 892

Expression: is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use)

Comment: Does this code even work? don't you need `waitKey(0)` for the imshow() to actually display. Also, maybe its because `imshow()` is using one of the frames that the rect is still being used?

Comment: There should be no reason to use `new` here for the vector.

Comment: @GPPK: `waitKey(1000 / 30)` means it will wait for a key, and it will try to run 30 frames per second. Everything works perfectly if I remove the `delete faces;` line (except there is a memory leak, of course).

Comment: @crashmstr: You're right, I chose to allocate it this way to make it explicit when the finalizer gets called. If I don't use `new`, it still crashes the same way at the end of the loop.

Comment: @MariusUt C++ does not have finalizers but destructors, and the destructor would get called at the end of the block anyway as the (non-pointer) variable goes out of scope. So not sure how what you are doing with `new` makes any difference

Comment: @crashmstr It doesn't make any difference. What I meant was, when posting my code here, I wanted to make it explicit that the crash occurred at `delete faces;`, but originally I hadn't written it that way. As you can surely guess, I'm from a .Net background, so I'm not sure it's "common knowledge" that the destructor is called as soon as the variable goes out of scope. Anyway, do you know anything that is helpful regarding my problem?

Comment: @MariusUt I would guess it is what GPPK said hours ago: `imshow` is holding onto resources in the vector, and the vector being deleted or going out of scope is causing undefined behavior as it still is using the data. You probably need to wait until the `imshow` is dismissed or done. Perhaps using a `waitKey` at the end of the loop instead of in the test?

Comment: @crashmstr: The `imshow` should not be related. The error still occurs if I remove that line. It should be noted that it works if the `detectMultiScale` is removed, and it also works as long as it finds no results.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue. I solved it by passing a dereferenced global pointer to the function.

I.e.

```
    std::vector<cv::Rect>* faces = nullptr;

    void init()
    {
        faces = new std::vector<cv::Rect>; //never call delete whatever you do
    }

    void findSomeFaces()
    {
        cascade->detectMultiScale(image_source, *faces);
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't this cause memory leak?

Comment: I asked that question because I had the same situation when I try to combine two projects that have their own memory management.
When I try to delete the allocated memory it still crashed. So right now I don't delete it at all, otherwise it crashes my program.

Comment: That's right, I had the same issue in my program, which is why I put in the cheeky comment. In theory it's a memory leak, however calling delete on a vector of cv::Rect (emptied or not) causes problems. Care must be taken not to continuously allocate cv::Rect vectors. Anything left over at the program end will be cleaned up by the OS. The problem lies somewhere within OpenCV's code.

Comment: Doesn't really fix the problem. I have tried it and it still crashed. I compiled to Release and it worked.